# Keymaps in Light Table are not working

Tags: python, lighttable

I just started learning Python with "A Byte of Python". I'm currently learning Light Table, the editor that the tutorial suggested.

This may be very amateurish but I have no experience whatsoever and this is all new to me.

I want to open console with cmd-shift-c so this is what my keymap looks like:

```
{:+ {:app {"cmd-shift-t" [:workspace.show]
           "cmd-shift-c" [:toggle-console]}
```

I click ctrl+shift+c and nothing happens, even after I save my keymaps file.

My editor commands work, though, when I unindent a line.

Comment: `cmd` and `ctrl` aren't the same thing.

Comment: you're also missing two closing braces `}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you said you clicked `ctrl+shift+c` I'm going to guess you're not on a Mac and should probably change your settings. I just tried the same thing as you have on my machine and it doesn't work.

However, changing it to `{"ctrl-shift-c" [:toggle-console]}` worked fine for me.